# Drawing Multiple Paths on A Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, path, drawing

I have a List of Geometry objects and I want to draw them in my WPF application.  This list of geometries are not configured to nicely scale within a given view so I'll need to somehow scale either each individual object, which could lead to problems or scale the container which I think is probably preferable.

I'm guessing I probably want to add my geometry objects to a canvas but I'm not sure.  I have no idea how to determine the correct way to transform a canvas to nicely display its content.

I'm just looking for guidance on how to add geometries to a container (possibly a canvas) AND have the container automatically transform to nicely display its contents regardless of the original size of the geometries. I already know how to add geometries to a path, but I don't know how to scale the canvas correctly to display it children in a nicely zoomed and centered fashion:

```
path.Data = geometry[i];
canvas.Children.Add(path);
```

As an example, suppose I wanted to draw a map of the world by country using just a basic rectangular map.  Suppose the countries are centered around the USA and the coordinates are in miles so the shapes are unrealistically large.  How would I add each country to a container and then display the total world map centered on the international dateline?  If the map were not scaled and translated it would just render a solid color because the map would be sooo far zoomed on Kansas.

Answer (score 0):

A [`Viewbox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx) will do the scaling for you and a canvas inside it as container for the paths seems fine as well, but the canvas needs to be set to the actual size of the map i think as it does not scale to its children.

Comment: Thats part of my problem.  The canvas doesn't scale and its possible that the size of the geometries is thousands of pixels square.  I need to figure out how to scale the canvas while scaling its contents.  You can't just scale each path by 50%; if you have a checker board and you scale each square 50% you end up with gaps.  You'd have to scale and translate by a variable amount.  This all seems to complicated there has to be a better way.

Comment: Actually you can scale each square, you only need to choose a common center. You can also add multiple paths to a Grid which should size to its children but the layout might end quite weird if the shapes are independent as they are going to end up in a stack of sorts.

Comment: Yeah the stack thing happens in that situation.  I can just set the transformOrigin=(0,0) for each path before I scale, but I still need to know how to transform the canvas to display its children paths nicely.  I know enough about WPF to be dangerous;  I could be thinking/going about this completely wrong.